# CIColorMatrix bias with alpha

Tags: ios, core-image, ciimage

So I'm trying to remove the alpha channel from an image.  I figured I'd try CIColorMatrix.  Now, here's the thing.  `filter` is a previously (successfully) applied filter.  The following code works like you think it would:

```
ciImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMatrix"];
[filter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1 Y:0 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputRVector"];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:1 Z:0 W:0] forKey:@"inputGVector"];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:1 W:0] forKey:@"inputBVector"];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0.75] forKey:@"inputAVector"];
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0.0] forKey:@"inputBiasVector"];
image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey]];
```

It multiplies alpha by 0.75.  However, if I change the alpha bias to be so much as 0.01:

```
[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:0.01] forKey:@"inputBiasVector"];
```

the resulting CIImage has preposterous `extent`, such as approximately `(-1.7e38, -1.7e38), (3.4e38 x 3.4e38)`.  I haven't tried to relocate it to see if the actual image is correct.

Anybody know why this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out.  Apparently it's not an uncommon thing for some filters to extend the `extent` infinitely.  The solution for that is to do

```
CGRect origExtent = ciImage.extent;
```

to your original `ciImage`, do filters (setting `ciImage` to be the result each time), and then call

```
ciImage = [ciImage imageByCroppingToRect:origExtent];
```

immediately before obtaining your final `UIImage` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the alpha channel the correct filter is color clamp setting the alpha value range to 1..1 and the other color channels to 0..1:

```
    CIFilter *clamp = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorClamp"];
    [clamp setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [clamp setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0 Y:0 Z:0 W:1] forKey:@"inputMinComponents"];
    [clamp setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:1 Y:1 Z:1 W:1] forKey:@"inputMaxComponents"];
    image = [clamp valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but sorry, it's been so long I can't really remember even what I was doing at the time.  Plus, it looks like I'd answered my own question, anyway.  But it does look like I forgot to mark my answer as such.